# Why subscripts are missing in the labels?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to display the subscript in the labels in the bar plot. Labels are the keys from the dictionary data in the following. I know how to use latex to do so, but I need to display it as it is from the keys in the dictionary. When I use the following script, it just displays the empty box, instead of the subscript.
[image]

```
import numpy as np

data = {'CO₆': 15,
 'DO₄': 144,
 'EO₈': 3,
 'FaO₉': 1,
 'GO₅': 7,
 'Ha₆': 5}

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (40, 4))

bin = np.arange(len(data.keys()))

ax.bar(data.keys(), data.values(), color='brown', align = "center", width = 0.3);

plt.xticks(rotation='vertical');

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 32);

ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 32);

plt.xlim(-0.5, bin.size-0.5);
```

Comment: Is it working in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font that you are using must not have those unicode characters.
Try [changing](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html?highlight=rcparams) the [font](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/font_family_rc_sgskip.html), this one works for me:

```
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['DejaVu Sans']
```

To use a Serif font:

```
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['DejaVu Serif']
```

Comment: This works. Thank you so much. Is there a way to update this for times new roman?

Comment: On my system, Times New Roman does not have those glyphs. You will need to choose another serif font. I've amended my answer with how.